# Cannot vertical align inline-block divs

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I was reading about how to align divs beside each other, and some posts recommended using `inline-block` instead of `float`. So I tried to do the same, but the vertical-align for the divs isn't working. Here's an example of my code:

```css
.container *{
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headers, .items{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tile{
  background: #27ae60; 
  width: 200px; 
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px; 
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.tile a, .tile span{
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.iconOpener{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <ul class="headers">
      <li class="header">
        <span> *  </span><span class="headerText">header 1</span>
        <a href="#" class="headerLink bold iconOpener" title="Open link in new tab">&#10532;</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header">
        <span> + </span> <span class="headerText">header 1</span>
        <a href="#" class="headerLink bold iconOpener" title="Open link in new tab">&#10532;</a>

        <ul class="items">
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="header">
        <span> + </span><span class="headerText">header 1</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also if there's any other recommended way to implement how tiles would be implemented, that'd be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the line `vertical-align:top` to the `.tile` class in your css. Then it works :) See snippet

```css
.container * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headers,
.items {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tile {
  vertical-align: top; /*added this*/
  background: #27ae60;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tile a,
.tile span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.iconOpener {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <ul class="headers">
      <li class="header">
        <span> *  </span><span class="headerText">header 1</span>
        <a href="#" class="headerLink bold iconOpener" title="Open link in new tab">&#10532;</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header">
        <span> + </span> <span class="headerText">header 1</span>
        <a href="#" class="headerLink bold iconOpener" title="Open link in new tab">&#10532;</a>

        <ul class="items">
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" class="itemLink">item 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="header">
        <span> + </span><span class="headerText">header 1</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel. How do you know the default values like, vertical-align, would it ALWAYS by default be baseline, or it's just baseline when inline-block is set? so then I need to set it to top? I am having problems understanding default values to props and whether these default values change based on other properties. If you have any tips for me would be great.

Comment: @DMZ simply read the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align the initial value is always the same and it doesn't depend on anything else ... in this case it's always baseline everywhere until you change it

Comment: @DMZ if you are in doubt about default values for a css attribute, you can check it on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp or in mozilla developers reference docs

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, but, how do I know in the first place that it's a vertical align issue, I mean I would never figure that by myself, how do you guys know that the problem is related to a specific property?

Comment: @RachelGallen I checked that url, it doesn't say baseline anywhere :S

Comment: @DMZ you face it one time, you become crazy searching what it is, you find it and you keep it in mind ;) ... that's how we learn and we become experienced, there is no magic trick

Comment: @TemaniAfif Appreciate your guidance .. not just for this question :)